# Method checking to get the range of the three variables under two constraints

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

Suppose a,b,c are real numbers and $a+b+c= 6$ , and $ab+bc+ca = 9$ , also $a<b<c$ find range of a , b, c .

> My method was on eliminating c we get $a^2 + b^2 -6a - 6b +ab + 9$ = 0 so making a quadratic in a in terms of b we get a = $\frac {6-b \pm √[(b-6)^2 - 4(b-3)^2 ]}{2}$ , substituing this into the inequality of $a<b$ , and solving for range of $b$ we get it to be $(3,4)$ , but answer is its range is $(1,3)$ , and $c$ is $(3,4)$ , $a$ is $(0,1)$ respectively  , may anyone tells whats going wrong here ?in my method and how to get thr ranges of $a$ and $c$ respectively from my method only .
> Note : i once tried with interchanging and making quadratic in  $b, c$ i got $b=f(c)$ then solve for $f(c)<c$ it lead me value of $c$ to be in $(3,4)$ , now solving for range of $b$ would be just checking the values $f(c)$ gets in the domain of $(3,4)$ but the problem is $f(c)$ is not actually a function because it has two values for same c  so how will we solve it? Although putting the domain give the range of b to be $(1,3)$ and then $0<6-b-c =a<1$   ,but how to check for b values as f is not a function , also whats wrong with the $a =f(b)$ part which was giving wrong range for b ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\,p=abc\,$ then by [Vieta's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) relations $\,a,b,c\,$ are the roots of $\,f(x)=x^3 - 6 x^2 + 9 x - p\,$. For the [cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation) to have real and distinct roots, its [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Degree_3) must be [positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Nature_of_the_roots) $\,\Delta = -27 (p^2 - 4 p) \gt 0\,$ $\,\iff p \in (0,4)\,$.

Writing the cubic as $\,f(x) = x(x-3)^2 - p\,$, it is easily verified that when $\,0 \lt p \lt 4\,$:

- $f(0) = f(3) = -p \lt 0$
- $f(1) = f(4) = 4 - p \gt 0$

It follows that $\,f(x)\,$ has at least one root in each of the intervals $\,(0,1), (1,3), (3,4)\,$ and, since it cannot have more than three roots in total, it must have exactly one root in each interval.

Comment: I understood your method , may you tell is my method not correct , as we are getting inequality in +- form s so its rather tends to give wrong answer ? @dxiv

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer Your approach could probably be made to work, but you need to be careful with all the signs and conditions. Why you get the wrong result is harder to guess since you don't provide details about "*solving for range of $b$ we get it to be $(3,4)$*".

Comment: Okay , can i rectify and then share here what i did ?  I think then i will be cleared with my approach too

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer You can [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4445237/edit) the question and add the missing details.

Answer (score 1):

We have a plane $ a + b + c = 6 $ and the hyperboloid of two sheets $ab + ac + bc = 9 $

The intersection of the two is a circle of center $(2,2,2)$ and radius $\sqrt{6}$

Hence, the vector $v = (a,b,c) $ can be described parametrically as

$ v = (2,2,2) + \sqrt{6} \left( \cos(t) \dfrac{(1, -1, 0)}{\sqrt{2}} + \sin(t) \dfrac{(1, 1, -2)}{\sqrt{6}} \right) \\= (2 + \sqrt{3} \cos(t) + \sin(t), 2 - \sqrt{3} \cos(t) + \sin(t) , 2 - 2 \sin(t) )$

Since we want $ a \lt b \lt c $, then we want

$  \sqrt{3} \cos(t)  \lt - \sqrt{3} \cos(t) $

and

$ - \sqrt{3} \cos(t) + \sin(t) \lt - 2 \sin(t) $

The first equation implies that $ t \in (\dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{3 \pi}{2}) $

And the second eqauation implies

$ 3 sin(t) \lt \sqrt{3} \cos(t) $

Since, from the first inequality, $\cos(t) \lt 0 $, then

$ \tan(t) \gt \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} $

whose solution is $ t \in [ \dfrac{7\pi}{6} , \dfrac{3\pi}{2} ] $

and this is the overall range.  What remains is to find the range of the functions $a,b,c$ over this interval.

The easiest is $c = 2 - 2 \sin(t) $ , so its range is $[ 3 , 4 ]$

Then we have $ a = 2 + \sqrt{3} \cos(t) + \sin(t) = 2 + 2 \cos(t - \dfrac{\pi}{6} )$, therefore, its range is $[0, 1] $

And finally, $ b = 2 - \sqrt{3} \cos(t) + \sin(t) = 2 - 2 \cos( t + \dfrac{\pi}{6} )$, therefore, its range is $[1, 3] $

Comment: I understood your method , may you tell is my method not correct , as we are getting inequality in +- form s so its rather tends to give wrong answer ?